# Не работает CronTab, задачи не запускаются

Tags: linux, crontab, armbian-linux

Пытаюсь создать задачу `cron` на армбиане, создаю через `crontab -e` такую задачу на выполение каждую минуту:

```
*/1 * * * * /root/script/update.sh&
```

и при перезагрузке:

```
@reboot  /root/script/update.sh&
```

Но ничего не происходит, делаю все операции из под root пользователя (да это не очень правильно с точки зрения безопасности, но работать то должно)

`ps ax | grep cron` возвращает

```
 1680 ?        Ss     0:00 /usr/sbin/cron -f
 1788 ttyS0    S+     0:00 grep --color=auto cron
```

С `env -i /bin/bash --noprofile -norc` командой `/root/script/update.sh&` все отлично запускается

Содержимое update.sh:

```
node /root/script/index.js test
```

Comment: Попробуйте добавить `SHELL=/bin/bash` в начало файла, который вы редактируете через `crontab -e`, там где `*/1 * * * * /root/script/update.sh&`

Comment: Кстати говоря не ставьте амперсанд в конце, он в данном случае ни к чему.

Comment: Ну и да. если мы говорим про системные задачи, будет правильно их создавать не для пользователя (root ведь тоже пользователь), а в соответствующих файлах настройки.  Я имею в виду что системные задачи правильнее создавать в /etc/cron.d  папке ибо системные задачи по-хорошему должны быть "пользователе независимы".

Comment: Как бы то ни было глупо , но похоже он не видел Nodejs (`node`) в `update.sh`, хотя я даже пробовал прописывать `PATH` в `crontab -e`, решил прописыванием путя до nodejs (/usr/local/bin/node) в место кoманды `node`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Проблема заключалась в том что в `update.sh` не могло найти `node` хотя я прописывал в `crontab -e` `PATH` с путем до NodeJS - `/usr/local/bin`.

Но при этом в `env -i -profile -norc` все работало.

Решил проблему прописав в `update.sh` вместо

```
node /root/script/index.js test
```

так

```
/usr/local/bin/node /root/script/index.js test
```